# accelerometer on android

Tags: android, accelerometer

How to use Android **Accelerometer** feature to measure the distance when phone moved position? What is the best way to build this kind of application

[example on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vnc6JaXa_u4)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

Comment: a good tutorial about using android accelerometer http://www.quicktips.in/get-accelerometer-readings-android/

Answer (score 0):

Android Provide [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) for this.There are many samples are available which for creating such types of app.Below links may help you :

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-sensor/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it reliably.  For  true inertial navigation,  you need  accelerometer as well as hyroscopes.  For meassuring distance on plain surface, it could work.   You will have to

- listen to sensor values with maximal frequency phone gives you.
- integrate  values  over the time.

As your phone lies on flat surface,  you shall ignore respective acceleration component. 
You may also need some denoizing of acelerometer values -  chips used in phones are of miserable quality

Comment: konstantin, i tired to use accelerometer. i give up about that.. i just want to measure near distance, just about 20 cm - 30 cm. can u give me idea? how if i use proximity sensor on android. is it posible?

Comment: AFAIK, proximity sensor is optical  and is used  to disable touch screen when you put phone to your ear.  And it shouldbe possible to integrate distance traveled on flat horizontal surface via accelerometer.

Comment: yes proximity is used to disable touch screen. how to calculate the distance from proximity sensor? and how far?